# get success or failure confirmation npm trash

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to get javascript trash the return value? i need to confirm the operation is success or not related to this trash function:

```js
const trash = require('trash');

(async () => {
    await trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png']);
})();
```

i've trying this:

```js
(async () => {
    await trash(filename).then( function(val) {
        console.log(val)
    })
})()
```

**[UPDATE]**
also this:

```js
trash(filename).then(value => {
    console.log(value)
})
```

i dont know how to get return value from this function.
reference: [sindresorhus/trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash)

from youtube.com i found video about using trash

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2N7mpZ3v1Q
```

but still not answering my question. the question is updated. please help me.

Comment: Write: `const result = await trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png'])` Now use the `result`. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case trash promise returns a value, this is how to access it.

```js
// With async await await
(async () => {
    let value = await trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png']);
    // use value here
})();

// With promise
trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png']).then(value => {
    // use value here
})
```

#### Catching errors

```js
// catching error with async and await
(async () => {
    try {
        await trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png']);
        // Success
    } catch (ex) {
        // Failed with Error
        console.log('error', ex)
    }
})();

// catching error with Promise
trash(['*.png', '!rainbow.png']).then(() => {
    // Success
}).catch(ex => {
    // Failed with Error
    console.log('error', ex)
})
```

Comment: it's return undefined

Comment: This means trash is of void return type, so the default value is `undefined`

Comment: so, how to confirm this function is success or not?

Comment: You may try catching errors during the execution. I have updated the answer for the same in both scenarios.